# MongoDB Query based on value in array and return a single field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection called countries:

```
{
    "_id" : "123456",
    "enabled" : true,
    "entity" : {
            "name" : [
                    {
                            "locale" : "en",
                            "value" : "Lithuania"
                    },
                    {
                            "locale" : "de",
                            "value" : "Litauen"
                    }
            ]
    }
}
```

I like to return only the `ObjectId` and the `value` when the `locale` is "en".

```
 {"_id":"123456", "value":"Lithuania"}
```

Ideally renaming value to `country` for:

```
 {"_id":"123456", "country":"Lithuania"}
```

Using a projection like:

```
db.countries.aggregate([
    {$project: 
        {country: {$arrayElemAt:["$entity.name",0]}}
    }
])
```

returns almost the desired results:

```
 {"_id" : "1234565", "country" : { "locale" : "en", "value" : "Lithuania" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      country: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$entity.name",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$this.locale", "en" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { country: { $first: "$country.value" } } },
])
```

See [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oUIXULRWxlq)

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `entity.name` array, `$cond` check `locale` is `"en"` then return `value`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      country: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$entity.name",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.locale", "en"] },
              "$$this.value",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CNz_jZok9zh)

Answer (score 1):

I should have specified the MongoDB Version. Server is running 3.6.20. For that the following solution works:

```
db.countries.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      country: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$entity.name",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.locale", "en" ] }
        }
      }
    }
 },
  { $project: { country: { $arrayElemAt: [["$country.value"],0] } } },
])
```